# How to enable mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-12.04

I've installed lamp on an UBUNTU 12.04 64bit Server using tasksel. Everything is working properly. But Now I found that per-directory .htaccess apache overriding thing is not working.

I've searched on google about the possible cause.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-htaccess/

http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/htaccess-problems

But none of them is working.

I need to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com. So, I'm using the following code in my .htaccess file at server root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

</IfModule>
```

**Apache virtual host configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride ALL
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride ALL
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    ...........................
    ...........................
    ...........................
```

**apacha2.conf has this:**

```
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` on? If you're not sure, try running `a2enmod rewrite` from the terminal. Oh and is the file name `apacha2.conf` or `apache2.conf`? Also, don't forget to reload and restart apache after you make changes to any of the files you listed (not `.htaccess` but the rest): `service apache2 reload` and `service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Thank you @jerdiggity. `a2enmod rewrite` worked perfectly..

Comment: Cool. You're welcome. I'll add my comment as an answer then (so the question doesn't appear to remain unanswered), unless you want to answer your own question. Either way works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks like it's set up correctly, so chances are that `mod_rewrite` is not enabled. Try running `sudo a2enmod rewrite` from the terminal.

Also, don't forget to reload apache (`sudo service apache2 reload`) and then restart apache (`sudo service apache2 restart`) after you make changes to any of the files you listed (not `.htaccess` files since they are read on every request, but the rest of the files you listed).

HTH. :)